# Saving Drag & Drops with JQuery to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, local-storage

I have a drag and drop widget that I built in [*jQuery*](http://api.jquery.com/). I have the drag-and-drop's working great, but I need to be able to save the dropped items after the have been dropped. Basically, wherever the images are dropped to, I need that information to be saved via [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

I am fairly new to *jQuery*, so I'm not sure how to save the position of the dropped images into the `localstorage`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my drag and drop *jQuery* code.

```
$("#circle").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: 'move'
});

$("#DragContainer").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var $canvas = $(this);
        if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('canvas-element')) {
            var $canvasElement = ui.draggable.clone(); // This code allows for multiple copies.
            $canvasElement.addClass('canvas-element');
            $canvasElement.draggable({
            });

            $canvas.append($canvasElement);
            $canvasElement.css({
                left: (ui.position.left),
                top: (ui.position.top),
                right: (ui.position.right),
                bottom: (ui.position.bottom),
                position: 'absolute'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The droppable area is set up as a `<canvas>` element. I have gotten this to work before on a sketchpad widget, but can't seem to figure it out on a drag and drop.

Comment: As an aside: I tend to use the jQuery extended cookies plugin for localStorage. Easy to use even if you don't strictly need cookie fallback. As for the question, what is the identifier for how they are stored and read back in? Does the location need to be saved, or just the order that it's dropped? In general, to store an object you will need to stringify it and then save it to localStorage. In other words, does $canvasElement have everything you need to recreate the scenario on subsequent page loads?

Comment: The location needs to be saved. I have 2 images, one is the Droppable Area (canvasDrag) and the second is the Draggable Item (image1). Image 1 can be dragged and dropped anywhere onto the canvasDrag, but then i need the location of where that image is dropped to be saved in localStorage. How would I go about stringifying this in JQuery? Thanks so much!

Comment: The question requires a bit more design before a useful answer can be written. You can store any object or array you want by stringifying it and using the localStorage API. A useful answer will be written knowing what should be stored and when.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm a little lost...

Comment: It happens, Mike. ;) My advice is to break your question up into more instantly-answerable questions with specific problems. The design of the application isn't known, so it's hard to make an answer. If you break it down into component parts and ask one at a time it seems a bit more roundabout but you will get better answers and they will come faster.

Comment: Great. Makes sense, huh. Thanks ski much for the help. Really the only question I have is I am just trying to save a drag and drop item to 'localStorage'. I am using _JQuery_ for the Drag & Drop function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best with what I have. Storing the drag and drop item depends on exactly what you're trying to store. So this code isn't instantly functional. The sample goes into your drop handler; it's not standalone.

First, I would personally include the jQuery Extended Cookies plugin if you need wide support in browsers... it will use localStorage when available, or serialized cookies when not.

```
var storeThis = JSON.stringify($canvasElement.attr('style')); // just an example!!
var identifier = function() { // who knows? some sort of function returning an identification string }

// this one if using Extended Cookie
$.cookie(identifier, storeThis, {expires: 365});

// this one if just using localStorage API
localStorage.setItem(identifier, storeThis);
```

It's not super useful... to make it useful you will need to know:

- the parts of the canvasElement (or the canvas itself?) that need to be stored, then a method for getting them
- the format you wish to store them in. With the above code, each item gets its own identifier in localStorage, but I have no idea what a useful identifier looks like in your application. But you don't have to do it this way; you could make an array of stored elements, stringify it, and store it to localHost

To retrieve these, one of two getters:

```
// with Extended Cookie
$.cookie(identifier);

// localStorage
localStorage.getItem(identifier)
```

If you need help with the array of objects idea, let me know and I can update the example.

Comment: What needs updating? Did the jQuery Extended Cookies plugin switch from the $.cookie(<string>) syntax?